# I get mass errors in production for "ActionController::RoutingError"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, production, unicorn

The problem is that those URLs, actions and views if you will are no longer there.
But my error log in production keeps screaming those errors even in config.log_level = :fatal

How can I resolve this globaly?

```
Rails 2.3.5
Ruby ruby 1.8.7 (2009-12-24 patchlevel 248) [x86_64-linux], MBARI 0x6770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2010.01
```

Here is the rake routes output:

```
         root    /                                        {:mode=>"popular", :controller=>"stories", :action=>"index"}
                 /popular/:category/:sort_option          {:mode=>"popular", :controller=>"stories", :action=>"index"}
                 /new/:category/:sort_option              {:mode=>"new", :controller=>"stories", :action=>"index"}
                 /popular/:category                       {:mode=>"popular", :controller=>"stories", :action=>"index"}
                 /new/:category                           {:mode=>"new", :controller=>"stories", :action=>"index"}
                 /popular                                 {:mode=>"popular", :controller=>"stories", :action=>"index"}
                 /new                                     {:mode=>"new", :controller=>"stories", :action=>"index"}
                 /follow/follow/:id                       {:controller=>"follow", :action=>"follow"}
                 /follow/unfollow/:id                     {:controller=>"follow", :action=>"unfollow"}
                 /follow/:sort_option                     {:controller=>"follow", :action=>"index"}
                 /follow                                  {:controller=>"follow", :action=>"index"}
                 /story/submit_by_url                     {:controller=>"story", :action=>"submit_by_url"}
                 /story/vote/:id                          {:controller=>"story", :action=>"vote"}
                 /:id                                     {:controller=>"story", :action=>"index"}
                 /:id/:action                             {:controller=>"story"}
                 /story/:action                           {:controller=>"story"}
                 /story/:category/:id                     {:controller=>"story", :action=>"old_index"}
                 /story/:category/:id/who_voted           {:controller=>"story", :action=>"old_who_voted"}
                 /tag/cloud                               {:controller=>"tag", :action=>"cloud"}
                 /tag/:tag_name/:filter                   {:controller=>"tag", :action=>"index"}
                 /tag/:tag_name                           {:controller=>"tag", :action=>"index"}
                 /site/:domain/:filter                    {:controller=>"site", :action=>"index"}
                 /site/:domain                            {:controller=>"site", :action=>"index"}
                 /search                                  {:controller=>"search", :action=>"index"}
                 /profile/:username                       {:controller=>"profile", :action=>"index"}
                 /profile/:username/:action               {:controller=>"profile"}
                 /account/settings                        {:controller=>"settings", :action=>"index"}
                 /account/settings/:action                {:controller=>"settings"}
                 /feed/:category(.:format)                {:controller=>"feed", :action=>"index"}
                 /feed/:old_site_route/site.xml           {:controller=>"feed", :action=>"index"}
                 /rss/:old_site_route/:category(.:format) {:controller=>"feed", :action=>"index"}
                 /sitemaps/index(.:format)                {:controller=>"sitemaps", :action=>"index"}
                 /sitemaps/:action.:number(.:format)      {:controller=>"sitemaps"}
                 /home/fresh                              {:controller=>"home", :svejo_type=>"fresh", :action=>"list_stories"}
                 /home/green                              {:controller=>"home", :svejo_type=>"green", :action=>"list_stories"}
                 /user/profile                            {:controller=>"user", :action=>"login"}
                 /profile/:id/publications                {:controller=>"profile", :show=>"published", :action=>"actions"}
                 /profile/:id/voted                       {:controller=>"profile", :show=>"voted", :action=>"actions"}
                 /profile/:id/friends/:action             {:controller=>"friends"}
                 /profile/:id/conversations/:action       {:controller=>"conversations"}
                 /profile/:id/:action                     {:controller=>"profile"}
                 /:controller/service.wsdl                {:action=>"wsdl"}
                 /accelerators/:action(.:format)          {:controller=>"accelerators"}
                 /home/story_summary/:id                  {:controller=>"summary", :action=>"link"}
                 /home/link_summary/:id.:extension        {:controller=>"summary", :action=>"link"}
                 /home/link_summary/:id                   {:controller=>"summary", :action=>"link"}
                 /administration/featured_stories/:action {:controller=>"administration/featured_stories"}
                 /portfolio                               {:controller=>"home", :action=>"portfolio"}
last_dayblogs GET    /api/dayblogs/last(.:format)             {:controller=>"api/dayblogs", :action=>"last"}
 new_dayblogs GET    /api/dayblogs/new(.:format)              {:controller=>"api/dayblogs", :action=>"new"}
edit_dayblogs GET    /api/dayblogs/edit(.:format)             {:controller=>"api/dayblogs", :action=>"edit"}
     dayblogs GET    /api/dayblogs(.:format)                  {:controller=>"api/dayblogs", :action=>"show"}
              PUT    /api/dayblogs(.:format)                  {:controller=>"api/dayblogs", :action=>"update"}
              DELETE /api/dayblogs(.:format)                  {:controller=>"api/dayblogs", :action=>"destroy"}
              POST   /api/dayblogs(.:format)                  {:controller=>"api/dayblogs", :action=>"create"}
                     /api/stories/:action                     {:controller=>"api/stories"}
                     /api/tags/:action                        {:controller=>"api/tags"}
                     /public_api/user/:id/:action(.:format)   {:controller=>"public_api/user"}
                     /public_api/tag/:id/:action(.:format)    {:controller=>"public_api/tag"}
                     /public_api/stories/:action(.:format)    {:controller=>"public_api/stories"}
                     /public_api/comments/:action/:format     {:controller=>"public_api/comments"}
                     /public_api/site/:id/:action(.:format)   {:controller=>"public_api/site"}
                     /:controller/:action/:id                 
                     /:controller/:action/:id(.:format)
```

Here is a sample of the error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/1021677.." with {:method=>:get}):
haml (3.0.24) rails/./lib/sass/plugin/rack.rb:41:in `call'
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/hoptoad_notifier-2.4.2/lib/hoptoad_notifier/rack.rb:27:in `call'
unicorn (2.0.1) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:510:in `process_client'
unicorn (2.0.1) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:585:in `worker_loop'
unicorn (2.0.1) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:583:in `each'
unicorn (2.0.1) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:583:in `worker_loop'
unicorn (2.0.1) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:473:in `spawn_missing_workers'
unicorn (2.0.1) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:470:in `fork'
unicorn (2.0.1) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:470:in `spawn_missing_workers'
unicorn (2.0.1) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:466:in `each'
unicorn (2.0.1) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:466:in `spawn_missing_workers'
unicorn (2.0.1) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:480:in `maintain_worker_count'
unicorn (2.0.1) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:163:in `start'
unicorn (2.0.1) lib/unicorn.rb:13:in `run'
unicorn (2.0.1) bin/unicorn_rails:208
/opt/ruby/bin/unicorn_rails_svejo:23:in `load'
/opt/ruby/bin/unicorn_rails_svejo:23
```

Thanks!

Comment: please add the output of `rake routes`.

Comment: OK edited the post to include the `rake routes` output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't be so worried.
Many bots are checking your website for drupal holes and joomla vulnerabilitie